# Django ical with Vobject issue with pytz

Tags: python, django, timezone, pytz, vobject

I am using vobject to create a ical event in Django. I am having trouble with the lower level code. It looks like ical is trying to grab a timezone with `obj.add(TimezoneComponent(tzinfo=getTzid(tzid)))`. But then I get `raise NonExistentTimeError(dt)` from pytz. Any suggestions on what to do? The year, month, day show correctly as I viewed them with the print statement in for variable start1.

```
 File "/home/git/chrono/chrono/requests_app/views.py", line 110, in form_valid
    ics_form = create_ics(data)
  File "/home/git/chrono/chrono/requests_app/views.py", line 126, in create_ics
    response = HttpResponse(cal.serialize(), content_type='text/calendar')
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/chronos/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/base.py", line 186, in serialize
    return behavior.serialize(self, buf, lineLength, validate)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/chronos/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/behavior.py", line 147, in serialize
    cls.generateImplicitParameters(obj)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/chronos/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/icalendar.py", line 853, in generateImplicitParameters
    obj.add(TimezoneComponent(tzinfo=getTzid(tzid)))
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/chronos/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/icalendar.py", line 75, in __init__
    self.tzinfo = tzinfo
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/chronos/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/base.py", line 468, in __setattr__
    prop.fset(self, value)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/chronos/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/icalendar.py", line 145, in settzinfo
    transition = getTransition(transitionTo, year, tzinfo)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/chronos/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/icalendar.py", line 1856, in getTransition
    uncorrected = firstTransition(generateDates(year, month, day), test)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/chronos/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/icalendar.py", line 1816, in firstTransition
    if not test(dt):
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/chronos/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vobject/icalendar.py", line 1843, in test
    def test(dt): return tzinfo.dst(dt) != zeroDelta
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/chronos/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/tzinfo.py", line 445, in dst
    dt = self.localize(dt, is_dst)
  File "/home/one/.virtualenvs/chronos/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz/tzinfo.py", line 327, in localize
    raise NonExistentTimeError(dt)
NonExistentTimeError: 2000-04-02 02:00:00



def create_ics(data):
    start1 = data['date_due']
    print start1.day
    start2 = datetime.datetime(start1.year, start1.month, start1.day)
    start3 = data['action']
    cal = vobject.iCalendar()
    cal.add('method').value = 'PUBLISH'
    vevent = cal.add('vevent')
    vevent.add('dtstart').value = start1
    vevent.add('dtend').value = start2
    vevent.add('dtstamp').value = datetime.datetime.now()
    vevent.add('summary').value = data['action'].name
    response = HttpResponse(cal.serialize(), content_type='text/calendar')
    response['Filename'] = 'filename.ics'
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.ics'
    return response
```

from models, the datetime field:

```
date_due = models.DateTimeField()
```

UPDATE:

Found I had to place:

```
>>> utc = vobject.icalendar.utc
>>> start = cal.vevent.add('dtstart')
>>> start.value = datetime.datetime(2006, 2, 16, tzinfo = utc)
```

into it, which worked.

Comment: I tried adding that code, but I still have the same crash. Does anybody have an idea where the 2000 date is coming from, or why adding another event fixed the crash for @dman?

Comment: it's been a long time, so many things could of changed in the django world :)

Comment: I don't think this bug actually has anything to do with Django. In my case, I found that I was calling `pytz.timezone.normalize()` unnecessarily before converting to iCalendar. I removed the call and the crash went away.

Comment: I still have no idea where the 2000 date came from.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** vobject is not (as of 0.9.2) compatible with pytz. So make sure *every* datetime in your vobject iCalendar has been converted to UTC before trying to serialize it, using something like `.astimezone(pytz.utc)`.

(That's *every* dtstart, dtend, dtstamp, created, last-modified, and maybe some other vevent fields I've forgotten.)

**Long answer:** vobject tries to do the right thing for non-UTC datetimes, but runs into trouble with pytz. The "right thing" comes from [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) which specifies iCalendar:

1. Represent the datetime using [DATE-TIME Form #3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5) "date with local time and time zone reference". That might be something like `DTSTART;TZID=America/New_York:20160714T133000` -- notice the TZID for your event's timezone.
2. Add a [VTIMEZONE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.6.5) block to your iCalendar for each unique TZID used in your events. This is a *complete definition* of that timezone: how to figure out that timezone's offset from UTC for any datetime that might appear, including daylight savings time rules. (RFC 5545 [doesn't specify](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.19) any particular timezone names, so you have to include timezone definitions in the iCalendar itself. vobject does this for you, automatically.)

To figure out the timezone conversion rules, vobject [searches through "all time"](https://github.com/eventable/vobject/blob/0.9.2/vobject/icalendar.py#L134-L291) (default years 2000-2030), looking for changes in the timezone's offset from UTC. And that's where things go wrong, because the vobject code doesn't handle pytz's invalid time errors.

2:00am April 2, 2000 is the first DST transition between 2000-2030, which is why you're getting an error about that time (even though you didn't use it anywhere in your own code).

**Options:**

- Use `date` instead of `datetime` if you don't want a specific time of day (as in the original question). Dates don't have timezones, so none of this applies. (And vobject handles dates just fine.)
- Convert all `datetime` to aware datetimes in UTC. UTC doesn't require a VTIMEZONE definition.
- Use [dateutil timezones](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tz.html) instead of pytz. E.g., `from dateutil import tz; ... tzinfo=tz.gettz('America/Los_Angeles')`. Since dateutil is a vobject dependency, I *think* this is the format vobject's VTIMEZONE generator is designed against. (But haven't tested extensively. Also, gettz requires tzdb files installed on your machine, so isn't entirely portable.)
- Add your own VTIMEZONE definitions to the iCalendar for every TZID you use, which should avoid the problematic auto-timezone-generation code in vobject. (Untested. And complicated to get right in the general case.)
- Submit a [PR to fix vobject to work with pytz](https://github.com/eventable/vobject/pull/33).